# How to design: Single blocking worker with multiple threads signalling for work

Tags: c#, swift, multithreading, concurrency, producer-consumer

I have a worker that when running will collect all available work and batch process it. Since it should not poll for available work it must block somewhere, then run and go back to blocking.

In parallel, I have operations that add work to the system, at time much faster than the worker can process. Work is not kept in memory so a queue with work is not possible. Each operation thus should signal the worker that at least some work is available.

```
1 Worker                N Producers
  ___                       ____
 /   \                     /    \
|    WAIT <------------ SIGNAL   |
|     |                   |      |
^     V                   ^      V
|     |                   |      |
|    WORK <- DATABASE <- ADD     |
 \___/                     \____/
```

I have yet to find a way to express this with standard tools and I need this to be implementable in at least C#, Swift and Typescript. All concurrency API I checked must be balanced so having more signals than waits is not allowed. Similar, I do not want to use a queue because it could grow too large and does not fit the problem well.

Questions

Without going into detailed code, what types, classes, methods or algorithms should I use to implement this scenario?

Is there any way to combine existing concurrency api like locks, semaphores, atomic types to accomplish my goal?

Why isn’t there a semaphore that can be signaled more times than the waits on it (like wait will clear all extra signals)?

Comment: Regarding the tools available with C#, this looks like a problem that can be solved with a `BlockingCollection<T>` (synchronously) or with a `Channel<T>` (asynchronously). Both of these components support backpressure (bounded capacity).

Comment: Any approach that suspends threads will be suboptimal. While there are legacy threading techniques involving these "Consumer - Provider" pattern (also suggested in .NET) which may lead to an unbound number of suspended threads, this is a no go for modern designs (IMHO) - no matter if this is running on a device, desktop or server. So, a better solution would be (non-blocking) event driven, possibly using FRP, i.e. some tools from the Rx family, Swift Combine, etc. FRP is available on all mentioned platforms. In any case: _async_ ;)

Comment: You should read [ask]. Your explanation is not at all clear to me.

Comment: @Enigmativity I read the HowToAsk and I don’t see how I could be more compliant. Since this is not a specific code problem I cannot give a code example and I tried to make the topic as defining as possible without making it too long. 

Zoulias: I stated the reasons for not using a queue. 

CouchDeveloper: You probably missed that I only need a single worker that is suspended at times. And polling is definitely not an option for an iOS framework.

Comment: @AndreasPardeike - A good question gets answers in minutes here. And I really didn't understand your explanation of what you're trying to do. Perhaps you could try to rephrase?

Comment: I edited my question. Does this make it clearer?

Comment: @theodor-zoulias While dismissing your reply at first, it looks to me that your suggestion is in fact the right track. Using a BlockingCollection with capacity 1 the worker will wait for an entry to begin work and the producers simply try to add to the (single) spot available if possible. Assuming the implementation of BlockingCollection is thread-safe, there will be no race condition. Is this what you suggested?

Comment: Andreas yes, the `BlockingCollection<T>` is thread-safe. In can be used concurrently by multiple producers and consumers. In case multiple consumers are waiting for an item, a new item added in the `BlockingCollection<T>` will be delivered to only one of the consumers, and the rest will keep waiting. There is a restriction though: the `CompleteAdding` method cannot be called by one producer, while another producer is blocked, waiting for space to `Add` an item (it's the last one out that should close the door).

Comment: Thanks Theodor. I won’t need `CompleteAdding` in my use case. As long as producers can try to add to a maxed out collection by simply failing to add, it will match the behavior of a [0,1] bound semaphore.

Answer (score 0):

```
import java.util.concurrent.ArrayBlockingQueue;
import java.util.concurrent.BlockingQueue;

public class consumeprodue<BlockingQue> {
    private static BlockingQueue<Integer> queue = new ArrayBlockingQueue<>(2);
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Thread p = new Thread() {
            public void run() {
                for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
                    try {
                        System.out.println(getName() + " produced :" + i);
                        queue.put(i);
                        Thread.sleep(200);
                    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }

            }

        };
        Thread c = new Thread() {

            public void run() {

                try {
                    while (true) {
                        System.out.println(getName() + "consume :" + queue.take());
                    }

                } catch (InterruptedException e) {

                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }

        };
        Thread d = new Thread() {

            public void run() {

                try {
                    while (true) {
                        System.out.println(getName() + "consume------- :" + queue.take());
                    }

                } catch (InterruptedException e) {

                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }

        };
        d.start();
        p.start();
        c.start();

    }

}
```

Comment: While this code may solve the question, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) of how and why this solves the problem would really help to improve the quality of your post, and probably result in more up-votes. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now. Please [edit] your answer to add explanations and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: Thanks for the effort but I explicitly stated that I do not want detailed code. I have to implement this in multiple languages and rather want someone explain to me which (software) tools to use.